# Criar uma variável de ambiente para usuários sem acesso a bash (/sbin/nologin)?

Tags: php, linux, shell

Estou tentando criar uma variável de ambiente que será acessada por um script php pelo usuário que roda o httpd (user: apache). Ele é definido como `/sbin/nologin` e portanto não acessa `.profile`, `profile`, `.bashrc`, etc...

Eu presuponho que esta varável tenha que ser carregada a nível global pelo SO (algo como `HOSTNAME`). Mas não estou conseguindo. Esta variável é uma string no formato json que contém os dados para conexão ao bancos de dados, credenciais de acesso, etc. Não sei se é a maneira mais segura de fazer isto, mas intuitivamente creio que sim. Veja um ex:

ambiente linux:

```
MY_VAR_DATA='{"driver":"mysql","host":"ip_host_remoto","user":"nome_do_usuario","password":"senha_do_usuario"}'  
export MY_VAR_DATA
```

no php:

```
$connData = json_decode(getenv('MY_VAR_DATA'), true);
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar fico agradecido.

Comment: Só incluir a declaração da variável no script de start do apache, aí ele já sobe declarando a variável (`/etc/init.d/apache` é o primeiro lugar que me vem à cabeça, mas em tempos de systemd vai saber onde isso pode estar). Dito isso, se precisar alterar alguma informação nesses dados vai também ter que reiniciar o apache (mesmo q ele tivesse um .profile isso seria verdade), então por que não declarar logo dentro do PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Pessoal a solução que encontrei foi colocar as variáveis no arquivo **/etc/sysconfig/httpd**, mas se você utilizar a função phpinfo() lista estas variáveis na seção Environment e isso a gente não quer.
Então eu fiz uma alteração no /etc/php.ini desabilitando as chamadas à esta função através da diretiva `disable_functions = phpinfo
Em versões mais novas do apache, a partir da 2.4.24 você deve editar o httpd.service com o comando a seguir:

```
# systemctl edit httpd
```

Dentro do editor você coloca as seguintes linhas:

```
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/httpd
```

Isto vai fazer com que o apache carregue as variáveis definidas no /etc/sysconfig/httpd, já que nas versões mais novas isto não é feita mais. Se você editar diretamente o arquivo httpd.service após cada atualização do apache este arquivo será sobrescrito tendo que alterar novamente o arquivo. A solução acima é permanente.